# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: module or inject running unit-tests in test.js file

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-jasmine, angular-mock

I'm getting an error in my terminal output from PhantomJS `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: module in www/signin/tests/signin.service.tests.js` and `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: inject in www/signin/tests/signin.service.tests.js` where they are called in the code below.

```
describe('signinService', function(){
  var controller,
      deferredSigin,
      signinServiceMock,
      stateMock,
      hasClass = function (element, cls) {
          return element.getAttribute('class').then(function (classes) {
              return classes.split(' ').indexOf(cls) !== -1;
          });
      };
  beforeEach(function(){
    module('app');
  });

  // disable template caching
  beforeEach(module(function($provide, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $provide.value('$ionicTemplateCache', function(){} );
      $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();
  }));

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $q){
    deferredSigin = $q.defer();
    signinServiceMock = {
      signin: jasmine.createSpy('signin spy').and.returnValue(deferredSigin.promise)
    };
    stateMock = jasmine.creatSpyObj('$state spy', ['go']);
    controller = $controller('SiginController', {
      '$state': stateMock,
      'signinService': signinServiceMock
    });
  }));
```

I have my unit-test.conf.js in the root of my application with file paths configured as shown

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      'www/lib/angular/angular.min.js',
      'www/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'www/app.js',
      'www/signin/services/*.js',
      'www/signin/*.js',
      'www/signin/tests/*.js'
    ],
    exclude: [
    ],
    preprocessors: {
    },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  });
};
```

I was following [this tutorial](http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-write-automated-tests-for-your-ionic-app-part-2/). It seems like angular-mocks isn't getting loaded. Not sure why. I'm passing it in the files in unit-test.conf.js

Comment: Could it be that your file paths should be '../www/...' instead of 'www/...' as these will be interpreted relative to where you're executing the script from. See https://github.com/ashteya/ionic-tutorial-dinnerapp/blob/master/tests/unit-tests.conf.js

Comment: @AndyHasIt she puts her unit-tests.conf.js in a 'tests' directory at the root of her project. That is why she needs 'www' proceeded by '../', to go outside the tests directory. I have unit-tests.conf.js at the root of the directory. I did that to make it easy to write unit tests within the component sub directories of my app.

Comment: I checked and it doesn't matter where you run from, its relative to where the conf file is. You can run "karma start --log-level debug" to see where it's looking for the files.